# binary to be decoded

Tags: cipher

Below is binary but it's translated from something else. I don't think a binary to text editor would work

00110001 00110010 00110100 00100000 00110001 00110101 00110000 00100000 00110001 00110101 00110001 00100000 00110001 00110110 00110011 00100000 00110000 00110100 00110000 00100000 00110001 00110110 00110001 00100000 00110001 00110110 00110101 00100000 00110001 00110100 00110101 00100000 00110001 00110110 00110011 00100000 00110001 00110110 00110100 00100000 00110001 00110101 00110001 00100000 00110001 00110101 00110111 00100000 00110001 00110101 00110110 00100000 00110000 00110100 00110000 00100000 00110001 00110110 00110111 00100000 00110001 00110100 00110001 00100000 00110001 00110110 00110011 00100000 00110000 00110100 00110000 00100000 00110001 00110110 00110011 00100000 00110001 00110110 00110101 00100000 00110001 00110110 00110000 00100000 00110001 00110110 00110000 00100000 00110001 00110101 00110111 00100000 00110001 00110110 00110011 00100000 00110001 00110100 00110101 00100000 00110001 00110100 00110100 00100000 00110000 00110100 00110000 00100000 00110001 00110110 00110100 00100000 00110001 00110101 00110111 00100000 00110000 00110100 00110000 00100000 00110001 00110100 00110010 00100000 00110001 00110100 00110101 00100000 00110000 00110100 00110000 00100000 00110001 00110101 00110000 00100000 00110001 00110100 00110001 00100000 00110001 00110110 00110010 00100000 00110001 00110100 00110100 00100000 00110000 00110001 00110101 00100000 00110000 00110001 00110010 00100000 00110000 00110001 00110101 00100000 00110000 00110001 00110010 00100000 00110000 00110101 00110001 00100000 00110000 00110111 00110010

Hint:

> maybe a base-8 digit conversion language would work?

Comment: In the future, I would suggest not telling us how it's encoded; makes it too easy!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was certainly harder!

The first step is to

> Convert the binary using ASCII. We get the following:
>
> 124 150 151 163 040 161 165 145 163 164 151 157 156 040 167 141 163 040 163 165 160 160 157 163 145 144 040 164 157 040 142 145 040 150 141 162 144 015 012 015 012 051 072

Now the trick is to

> Decode using *octal* to text ([here](http://www.unit-conversion.info/texttools/octal/#data)

and doing so gives us the answer:

> This question was supposed to be hard
>
> ):

Dont worry! It was, the hint gave it away for me however

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the hint, due to the hint it was not that hard though(first question I ever solved)

> ans = "This question was supposed to be hard  "

Method

> Convert all binary to octal like "00110001" becomes 61  .

> From the ascii table look corresponding char from octal value 61 -> '1'(char)

> Use these char in the data replacing each number , first three numbers
> 00110001 00110010 00110100 gives 61 62 64 which gives 124(61->1,62->2,64->4"from the above step")

> Result will be a string of numbers each is a 3 digit number, each word separated by spaces(spaces comes from the 2nd step 40 maps to (" ")).

> For each word(which is a number ) again look to the ascii table ,(124->T)find the corresponding char and the answer comes out .

Comment: dangit i thought it would be harder i wont put a hint this time

Comment: then it would be impossibly harder :)

Comment: i just posted a new one ITS SUPER HARD this time